# Google Maps API Business Location

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

Morning all.

I'm am currently using the below code to load my Google Map's API V3 at a specific long-lat, it's for a client and I'm wondering if I can load an infoWindow similar to the one the pops up on Google Maps with the business information, review stars etc.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat-long),
          disableDefaultUI: true,
          zoom: 16,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("location"),
            mapOptions);
        
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat-long);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position:point,
            map: map,
        });
    }
</script>
```

Is this done in a different API? If so could anyone point me to some helpful information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you might be looking for the Places API/Library:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details_responses

Not sure if it has everything you find on Google Maps.